# dynamic_cast<> fails but static_cast<> works

Tags: c++, dynamic-cast

In my project I have a scenario like suppose:

- 1) BaseClass is an interface  which derives from a parent class IFlow
- 2) ChildClass derives from it ie from Base class
- 3) In childClass Init function I am using `dynamic_cast` to cast the objet of IFlow to BaseClass which is as shown below:

  ```
  void ChildClass::init()
  {    
      IFlow* pFlow = someMethod(); //it returns the IFlow object pointer

      //this works for static cast but fails for dynamic cast    
      BaseClass *base =  dynamic_cast<BaseClass*>(pFlow) ;
  }
  ```

In the above code the 2nd line of `dynamic _cast` returns zero but if the `dynamic_cast` is changed to `static_cast` then the code works as expected . 
Please advice

Answer (score 8):

`dynamic_cast` will "not work" in two instances:

1. You have somehow compiled your code without RTTI. Fix your compiler settings.
2. The entire purpose of `dynamic_cast` is to *ensure* that the cast actually works. Casting from child to parent always works because every child of some type is guaranteed to be that type (the whole "all dogs are animals, but not all animals are dogs" thing). Casting from a parent to a child can fail if the object is not actually that child type. `dynamic_cast` will return a null pointer if the `IFlow` you give it is not actually a `BaseClass`.

   Furthermore, your `static_cast` does not work. It simply returns a value. A value which, if you ever use it, results in *undefined behavior*. So it only "works" in the sense that it returned a value you could attempt to use.

So one of these two things happened. Which one is up to you to find, since you didn't give us the implementation of `someMethod`.

Answer (score 1):

A `dynamic_cast<>` returns null (zero) if the cast is not legal.  In this case it's doing what you want: there is a problem somewhere in your inheritance tree.  (The `static_cast<>` "works" only because it's a sledgehammer; it forces the cast at compile time without any knowledge of the type that the pointer will actually have at runtime.)

Answer (score 1):

if it like this?:

```
class A
{
public:
    A(){a = 0;};
    virtual ~A(){};
protected:
    int a;
};
A *GetAInstance();

class B : public A
{
public:
    B() : A() {b = 1;};
    virtual ~B(){};
protected:
    int b;
};

class C: public B
{
public:
    C() : B() {};
    ~C(){};

    void CheckA()
    {
        A *pA = GetAInstance();
        B *pB = dynamic_cast<B*>(pA);  --> Here pB is NULL.
        B *pB2 = static_cast<B*>(pA);
    };
};

A *GetAInstance()
{
    A *pA = new A();
    return pA;
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    C *pC = new C();
    pC->CheckA();
    return 0;
}
```

This is because you are trying to set a parent pointer to its child pointer. In dynamic_cast it thinks it is not safe, so it set the child pointer to NULL, you can see pB above which is NULL. For child class may have more functions/member variables, you call these new functions/member variables would cause run time error. But static_cast doesn't care this, it is only a compiler time check not run time check. static_cast only cares if they have some relation ship. If they have, static_cast convert the pointer even doesn't care run time error. Please run this small sample and check pB2 is not NULL. :)

Hope useful. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

What type is being returned by someMethod()? It needs to be derived from BaseClass to allow dynamic_cast to work. You can't cast downwards if it's not the correct type.

Static cast works at compile time and the compiler will just turn the pointer over.